# txpool on private chain not working unable to submit txn from non-miner

Tags: go-ethereum, txpool, clique

I have a local test setup with 3 Geth nodes, of which 2 are miners (Clique) and 1 non-miner.

I noticed that submitted transactions are never synchronized with other nodes.

Consequently, on a non-miner, submitted transactions never make it to the blocks.

That can't be normal behavior with Clique, can it?

**Startup commands:**

Node1:
`geth --identity node1 --datadir node1/ --syncmode full --port 30304 --rpc --rpcport 8545 --bootnodes "enode://c0f96309ca5918bd0de1b69a0f062a590c7877681d7d69a370f3174cc3f137f200e024e86482ed3718c074a4d70488e09b7ff154dc5210ee0e890773646a25d8@127.0.0.1:30304" --nat none --networkid 2640 --gasprice 1 -unlock 0xe148888d6a894101a39b84da4d5f24c97f0ba3bd --password node1/password.txt --mine console`

Node2:
`geth --identity node2 --datadir node2/ --syncmode full --port 30305 --rpc --rpcport 8555 --ipcdisable --bootnodes "enode://c0f96309ca5918bd0de1b69a0f062a590c7877681d7d69a370f3174cc3f137f200e024e86482ed3718c074a4d70488e09b7ff154dc5210ee0e890773646a25d8@127.0.0.1:30304" --nat none --networkid 2640 --gasprice 1 -unlock 0x9d6189a2082a9df61d432cf384cb1f606cea1528 --password node2/password.txt --mine console`

Node3:
`geth --identity node3 --datadir node3/ --syncmode full --port 30306 --rpc --rpcport 8556 --ipcdisable --bootnodes "enode://c0f96309ca5918bd0de1b69a0f062a590c7877681d7d69a370f3174cc3f137f200e024e86482ed3718c074a4d70488e09b7ff154dc5210ee0e890773646a25d8@127.0.0.1:30304" --nat none --networkid 2640 --gasprice 1 -unlock 0xd134a62fb3d349c8ba2991dfba48e091544a8a13 --password node3/password.txt console`

**The nodes are connected**

(On Node1, Node2, Node3):

```
> net.peerCount
2
```

**Blocks are being mined and synchronized**

On Node3:

```
INFO [05-07|14:31:42] Imported new chain segment               blocks=1 txs=0 mgas=0.000 elapsed=0s      mgasps=NaN   number=2375 hash=8271c9…543b5e cache=0.00B
INFO [05-07|14:31:47] Imported new chain segment               blocks=1 txs=0 mgas=0.000 elapsed=0s      mgasps=NaN   number=2376 hash=9442d8…b5b467 cache=0.00B
INFO [05-07|14:31:52] Imported new chain segment               blocks=1 txs=0 mgas=0.000 elapsed=0s      mgasps=NaN   number=2377 hash=611ee5…02ba2e cache=0.00B
```

But if **I submit a transaction on a non-miner** Node3:

```
> personal.sendTransaction({from:'0xd134a62fb3d349c8ba2991dfba48e091544a8a13', to:'0xE0ca7d355F0CC6C1EECDA7Ce081353b7D87Aa1d7', value: 1},'redacted')
INFO [05-07|14:31:16] Submitted transaction                    fullhash=0x9d1f3fa3a4c0037daed01371bd57d2ca6876cdb3d088ec7917656f272ce6485d recipient=0xE0ca7d355F0CC6C1EECDA7Ce081353b7D87Aa1d7
"0x9d1f3fa3a4c0037daed01371bd57d2ca6876cdb3d088ec7917656f272ce6485d"
```

Then **nothing happens**. 
The transaction remains in "pending" status forever:

```
> txpool.inspect
{
  pending: {
    0xD134A62fB3D349c8ba2991dFbA48E091544A8a13: {
      0: "0xE0ca7d355F0CC6C1EECDA7Ce081353b7D87Aa1d7: 1 wei + 90000 gas × 0 wei"
    }
  },
  queued: {}
}
```

Empty blocks are still coming in on Node3:

```
> INFO [05-07|14:31:17] Imported new chain segment               blocks=1 txs=0 mgas=0.000 elapsed=0s      mgasps=NaN   number=2370 hash=33498f…5077c1 cache=0.00B
```

On other nodes there are no pending transaction at all:

Node1, Node2:

```
> txpool.inspect
{
  pending: {},
  queued: {}
}
```

Why is this and how to get transactions working on a non-miner?

Running Geth/v1.8.3-stable-329ac18e/windows-amd64/go1.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The miners were started with `--gasprice 1`, but the transaction didn't specify any gas price, so it defaulted to `0`, which can also be seen in the calculation "`90000 gas × 0 wei`".

0 < 1, so the transaction is rejected by the miners as ***underpriced***
(it works locally because local transactions are [exempt](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/0afd7675372798bd1a71c6a78472835a54d60b54/core/tx_pool.go#L573) from gas price limits).

To solve this issue, remove the gas price threshold at the miners (is OK for private chains only)

```
geth --mine --gasprice 0
```

Or specify some `gasPrice` with the transaction:

```
personal.sendTransaction({ from:xxx, to:xxx, value: 1, gasPrice: 1}, 'pw')
```

The downside is that some ether will be spent, so the `from`-address need to be sufficiently funded.

Comment: Thank you for the clue. In 2022 the command is ```geth --miner.gasprice 0``` and docs claims it is set to zero by default. Anyway my node1 has one pending tx in ```txpool``, but my node3 has zero pending tx. Did you meet this issue again?